# Error in installing puppet enterprise

Tags: linux, puppet, puppet-enterprise

I have downloaded the Puppet Enterprise 3.7 installer from the PuppetLabs website, 
but while installing I got the below error...

```
./puppet-enterprise-installer

ERROR: This is a supported platform, but this is not the installer for this platform. Please use the platform specific installer
(puppet-enterprise-3.7.2-el-6-x86_64).
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

** This only applies to the open source version **
Which distribution are you installing this on? The error is telling you to use the EL6 install package which is available on their yum repo. It's much easier if you just install their repo package:

```
rpm -Uhv http://yum.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs-release-el-6.noarch.rpm
```

and then run `yum install puppet facter`.

Comment: your rpm command will install the open source version of puppet. not puppet enterprise.

Answer (score 3):

You can get the `enterprise linux` puppet installer for 3.7.2 following this link.

https://s3.amazonaws.com/pe-builds/released/3.7.2/puppet-enterprise-3.7.2-el-6-x86_64.tar.gz

Looks to me like you downloaded it for the wrong linux distribution.

Hope this helps.